Flutter namespace error on building the app
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_blue'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
am trying to add bluetooth on my app using flutter blue

Don't use flutter_blue, flutter_blue_serial, and any dependencies that display the above error. Some of them haven't been updated in 3 years. You should use appropriate alternatives. If you're using BLE, I recommend flutter_blue_plus. For Classic, use flutter_blue_serial.
